# Compute unit vector u = ̇r/|r| and verify that r and ˆu are always perpendicular.

Tags: vectors

$$r(t) = A\cos(\omega t)\hat i −A\sin(\omega t) \hat j$$

I have found the magnitude to of $r(t)$ to equal $A$

I have found the derivative of $r(t)$ to be: $\dot r(t) =A\omega(-\sin(\omega t)\hat i −\cos(\omega t) \hat j)$

Thus to obtain unit vector I divided $\dot r(t)$ by the magnitude of $r(t)$ which gave me:

$$\omega(-\sin(\omega t)\hat i −\cos(\omega t) \hat j)$$

However,
In the solution to this question the derivative of $r(t)$ is denoted as $\dot r(t) = A\omega \times$ unit vector which is not consistent with my answer for the unit vector.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: magnitude of r(t) is Aw ,not A.

Comment: Is it the square root of (Acos (ωt))^2 + (-Asin (ωt))^2? I get A when I do that, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Oh ,there was a typo I meant magnitude of dervative r(t) is Aw ,not A as "...obtain unit vector I divided the derivative of r(t) by the magnitude of r(t)...." should be "..obtain unit vector I divided the derivative of r(t) by the magnitude of derivative of r(t).."

Comment: Your derivation of $\dot r(t)$ also consists of $A\omega$ times a unit vector. That is consistent with what you've told us about their derivation of it as well. What is your issue? Maybe you should tell us *what unit vector* they are claiming $\dot r(t)$ is proportional to. Then we could compare them to yours and understand what the issue is.

Comment: The instructions are just wrong. You get a unit vector by dividing any vector by its length, not some other length. You should be doing $\dot r/|\dot r|$. Note that your supposed unit vector most certainly does not have length $1$.